# Why does an error occur when loading an image?

Tags: php, file, laravel-8

I'm doing it on Laravel 8. There is a form in which there is a field for a photo - `foto_main`. When I use the store method, an error occurs.

In the form I write the following code:

```php
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.area.store') }}">
    @csrf
    <label for="name_area">Name Object: <span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control_ txt" name="name_area" placeholder="Name Object" required maxlength="100" style="width: 80%" value="{{ old('name_area') ?? $area->name_area ?? '' }}"><br>

    <label for="foto_main">Image:</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file txt" name="foto_main" id="foto_main" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">

    @isset($area->foto_main)
    <div class="form-group form-check">
        <img src="{{ asset($area->foto_main) }}" width="100px" />
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="remove" id="remove">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="remove">
            Delete image
        </label>
    </div>
    @endisset
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn hero-search__btn btn--main">Save</button>
</form>
```

In the controller I write the following code:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $params = $request->all();
    unset($params['foto_main']);

    if ($request->has('foto_main')) {
    $params['foto_main'] = $request->file('foto_main')->store('areas');
    }

    Area::create($params);
    return redirect()->route('admin.area.index');
}
```

the "areas" directory is not in the storage directory. An error occurs

> Call to a member function `store()` on null.

On the line where from the request field of the picture (foto_main). I tried to write to store. Why is this happening? How to correctly write an image to the storage\app\public\areas directory?

Comment: This is telling you that `$request->file('foto_main')` is `null`. Maybe post the form (in your question) you use to upload

Comment: @brombeer, corrected the question. The field cannot be empty, as it is in the form.

Comment: Your form is missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute - which is **required** for file uploads to work. Little refresher: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: fyi, the value for the `width` attribute must be an integer without a unit

Comment: Another fyi: the `for` attribute in a `<label>` should point to the `id` attribute of an input element. `for="name_area"` There is no element with an `id` of `name_area`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by brombeer, your main issue is that your form needs `enctype="multipart/form-data"` added to it. Please see the code and comments below (I have addded in suggestions from comments above too so that you have a full answer).

```html
<!-- You must include enctype="multipart/form-data" -->
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.area.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <label for="name_area">
        Name Object: <span class="req">*</span>
    </label>
    
    <!-- Added id="name_area" as it is needed label's for="" -->
    <!-- You can shorten your old() code -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control_ txt" name="name_area" id="name_area"
           placeholder="Name Object" maxlength="100" style="width: 80%" required
           value="{{ old('name_area', $area->name_area) }}">
    <br>

    <label for="foto_main">
        Image:
    </label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file txt" name="foto_main" id="foto_main"
           accept="image/png, image/jpeg">

    @isset($area->foto_main)
        <div class="form-group form-check">
            <!-- alt="" is a required tag -->
            <!-- width="" must not have units after the integer -->
            <img src="{{ asset($area->foto_main) }}" width="100" alt="">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="remove" id="remove">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="remove">
                Delete image
            </label>
        </div>
    @endisset
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn hero-search__btn btn--main">
        Save
    </button>
</form>
```